# How can I prompt the user inside a while read loop?

Tags: bash

For my purpose, I need to execute a shell command, achieve the output, and for each line ask user for prompt.
The problem is that on the read prompt, stdin buffer isn't empty

this is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

git branch -a | sed 's/remotes\/origin\///g'

echo "############################"

git branch -a | sed 's/remotes\/origin\///g' | while read line
do
        if [[ "$line" != *develop* ]] \
                && [[ "$line" != *master ]] \
                && [[ "$line" != *release/* ]] \
                && [[ "$line" != *hotfix* ]]
        then
                read -r -p "Do you want to delete branch $line <y/N>?" prompt
                echo $prompt
        fi
done
```

The line:

`read -r -p "Do you want to delete branch $line <y/N>?" prompt`

does not even display to video, and prompt variable show the result of line variable above.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a FD other than 0 (stdin), to leave the original stdin free for input from the user:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh; also, do not run with "sh scriptname"

while read -r line <&3; do
  line=${line#remotes/origin/}  # trim remotes/origin/ w/o needing sed
  case $line in
    *develop*|*master|*release/*|*hotfix*) continue ;;
    *) read -r -p "Do you want to delete branch $line <y/N>?" prompt
       echo "$prompt" ;;
  esac
done 3< <(git branch -a)
```

Here, we're using FD 3 for output from `git`, such that FD 0 is still stdin, available to read from the user; and then redirecting `<&3` on the explicit `read` where we want content from `git`.

Comment: (Flagged community wiki to avoid harvesting rep from a known dupe)

Comment: Receiving this error  on last line
syntax error near unexpected token `3'

Comment: @fstarred, what's your shell? `<()` is bash-only syntax; it won't work with `/bin/sh`. (You tagged your question bash, so you *shouldn't* be using `/bin/sh`).

Comment: ...that said, running it through [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net/), I *did* miss the `esac` to close the `case`. Oops. :)

Comment: Works like a charm!!! thank you very much mate